# longest subsequence with alternate signs

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of +ve and -ve integers. Write an algorithm to find longest subsequence with alternate signs.
If 0 is there in array, it can be considered as both +ve and -Ve.
Exampls : Array : 5,-9,4,0,-1,5,-5,3,0,2
Longest subsequence : [0,-1,5,-5,3,0,2] size: 7
I wrote one function, it's working fine , but is there any other better way?

```
void f (int A[],int N){
    int fIndex = 0;
    int eIndex = 0;
    int maxCount =0;
    int curCount =0;
    int start =0;

    for(int i=1;i<N;++i){
        if(A[i] > 0 && A[i-1]>=0){
            if(i>=2 && A[i-2] < 0){
            fIndex = i;
            curCount =0;
            }
        }

        if(A[i] < 0 && A[i-1] <=0){
            if(i>=2 && A[i-2] > 0){
                fIndex = i;
                curCount =0;
            }
        }

        if((A[i] > 0 && A[i-1] <= 0) || (A[i] <0 && A[i-1]>=0)){
            curCount++;
            if(curCount > maxCount){
                maxCount = curCount;
            }
            start = fIndex;
            eIndex = i;
        }else if(A[i] == 0){
            if(A[i-1]> 0){
                A[i] = -1;
            }
            curCount++;
            if(curCount > maxCount){
                maxCount = curCount;
            }
            eIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return maxCount+1;
}
```

Comment: How would you would like the algorithm to be better? Faster? Less memory?

Comment: It would be helpful if you just described your algortihm instead of expecting people to decipher your code.  That said, you look to be doing a scan through the array which is about as good as you can do.

Comment: It's interesting how people alternately ask **"give us code, not prose"** and **"less code, describe your algorithm"**, depending on circumstance. The key, I guess, is that the example should be minimal.

Comment: @Orch I'd come to the same conclusion. It's a `O(n)` method. I can't see there being a better way.

Comment: I feel its a DP problem since we have seen other problems with longest subarrays.I did not use DP

Comment: It could be done with DP but it would just use more memory and wouldn't be as time efficient.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two possibilities for alternation like -+-+... or +-+-.... so we can just use two counters and reset them when a number comes we don't like:

```
int max = 0;
int[] l = {0, 0};
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  if (a[i] == 0) {
    l[0]++;
    l[1]++;
    continue;
  }
  int s = ((i % 2 == 0 && a[i] < 0) || (i % 2 == 1 && a[i] > 0)) ? 0 : 1;
  l[1-s]++;
  if (l[s] > max)
      max = l[s];
  l[s] = 0;
}
return max >= l[0] && max >= l[1] ? max : (l[0] >= l[1] ? l[0] : l[1]);
```